# Logging Dynamic Input Values in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have quite a large form, several pages of which make use of some JS to dynamically add inputs whenever the user clicks a plus button, allowing them to add in extra jobs and what have you.

I have that portion of the form working.  My problem comes in trying to capture the dynamic fields in the PHP document.  I seem to only be getting the first values that are input into the form, and nothing from the dynamically added inputs.

***What I have Tried***

I've separated one of the pages of the form that has two such inputs and tried capturing the first level of inputs in PHP.  This is working properly.

***What I am Unsure Of:***

How do I create variables in PHP or the potentiality of variables so I can grab them later in php?

I've recreated the example here, but only the first question allows for dynamic inputs.  I just included the one js file:

http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/xEyzNm?editors=1010

```
HTML:
 <form action="putToToCSV.php" method="post" class="scholarshipForm">

                <div class="input-group" id="unit-level-involvement">
                    <label id="unitInvolvement">Unit Involvement *</label>
                    <div id="unitLevelInvolvement">
                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelPosition[1]" placeholder="Position/Committee" onBlur="this.placeholder='Position/Committee'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="oectaUnit_1" id="oectaUnit_1" placeholder="Unit" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />

                        <div class="clearFix"></div>

                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitPresident_1" id="unitPresident_1" placeholder="Unit President" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit President'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="date" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitYear_1" id="unitYear_1" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="button" value="+" onClick="addUnitInvolvement()" />
                    </div>
                 </div><!-- end of unit-level-involvement div-->

    </form><!--endForm-->
```

JS:

```
var i = 0;
function addUnitInvolvement()
{
    i++;
    var unitInvolvementDiv = document.createElement("div");
    unitInvolvementDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="four-lines" name="unitLevelPosition_'+i+'" placeholder="Position/Committee">  <input type="text" class="four-lines" name="oectaUnit_'+i+'" placeholder="Unit"> <input type="text" class="four-lines" name="unitPresident_'+i+'" placeholder="Unit President"> <input type="date" class="four-lines" name="unitYear_'+i+'"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeUnitInvolvement(this)">';

    document.getElementById("unitLevelInvolvement").appendChild(unitInvolvementDiv);
}

function removeUnitInvolvement(unitInvolvementDiv)
{
    document.getElementById("unitLevelInvolvement").removeChild(unitInvolvementDiv.parentNode);
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php


$unitLevelPosition_1 = $_POST["unitLevelPosition_1"];

$oectaUnit_1 = $_POST["oectaUnit_1"];

$unitPresident_1 = $_POST["unitPresident_1"];

$unitYear_1 = $_POST["unitYear_1"];

$provincialPosition_1 = $_POST["provincialPosition_1"];

$provincialDate_1 = $_POST["provincialDate_1"];

$piText_1 = $_POST["piText_1"];


echo $unitLevelPosition_1 . "<br>" . $oectaUnit_1 . "<br>" . $unitPresident_1 . "<br>" . $unitYear_1 . "<br>" . $provincialPosition_1 . "<br>" . $provincialDate_1 . "<br>" . $piText_1;

?>
```

Comment: you should use an array like `name="provincialPosition[1]"` in your html/javascript and then in php you could read them like `foreach($_POST["provincialPosition"] as $value){`

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but can you provide a clear example via the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array syntax - e.g. `name="unitLevelPosition[]"` then when the form is submitted in PHP, you can utilize `$_POST['unitLevelPosition']` as an array. I tried searching for reputable resources but haven't found much. However, take a look at [this page](https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2014/submit-an-array-with-a-html-form/), as well as [this one](https://davidwalsh.name/checkbox-form-input-arrays) (I know that pertains to checkboxes but the concept is the same).

```js
var i = 0;
function addUnitInvolvement()
{
    i++;
    var unitInvolvementDiv = document.createElement("div");
    unitInvolvementDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="four-lines" name="unitLevelPosition[]" placeholder="Position/Committee">  <input type="text" class="four-lines" name="oectaUnit[]" placeholder="Unit"> <input type="text" class="four-lines" name="unitPresident[]" placeholder="Unit President"> <input type="date" class="four-lines" name="unitYear[]"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeUnitInvolvement(this)">';

    document.getElementById("unitLevelInvolvement").appendChild(unitInvolvementDiv);
}

function removeUnitInvolvement(unitInvolvementDiv)
{
    document.getElementById("unitLevelInvolvement").removeChild(unitInvolvementDiv.parentNode);
};
```

```html
<form action="putToToCSV.php" method="post" class="scholarshipForm">

                <div class="input-group" id="unit-level-involvement">
                    <label id="unitInvolvement">Unit Involvement *</label>
                    <div id="unitLevelInvolvement">
                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelPosition[]" placeholder="Position/Committee" onBlur="this.placeholder='Position/Committee'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="oectaUnit[]" id="oectaUnit_1" placeholder="Unit" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />

                        <div class="clearFix"></div>

                        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitPresident[]" id="unitPresident_1" placeholder="Unit President" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit President'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="date" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitYear_1" id="unitYear_1" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
                        <input type="button" value="+" onClick="addUnitInvolvement()" />
                    </div>
                 </div><!-- end of unit-level-involvement div-->

    </form><!--endForm-->
```

For an example, see [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6v5w-uqi1) - you can see the PHP code to start, and press `F9` or click the button labeled `Run - F9` to run the code. After clicking the button labeled `Submit form` you should see the output of processing the data in $_POST.

Comment: Sam, on the php side, do I need to declare an initial value like I would with any other array? for example $unitLevelPosition = array();

Comment: No $_POST is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) - i can make an example on phpfiddle.org soon...

Comment: That would be wonderful.  Sorry, I'm very new to php integration

Comment: see the new paragraph I added to the answer, which contains [the link](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6v5w-uqi1) and some instructions for it (in case you haven't used phpfiddle.org before).

Comment: @Theodore Steiner I added a couple links in the first paragraph of my answer - to some resources about sending array data from HTML form elements. Hopefully they are helpful.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Sam! The resources/your work have been amazing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126123/discussion-between-theodore-steiner-and-sam-onela).